# How to control height of card fragment in android wear?

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view, wear-os

I have an customized chart in card fragment which is a card showed on my LG G watch , I want to make it show in just one page without scrolling down.I tried to use LayoutParams and make it wrap content,but it does not work. ps: I'm using the GridViewPager widget.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to make it looks like the what the 3rd pic shows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 
`android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Here is a [sample app](https://github.com/mauimauer/AndroidWearable-Samples/tree/master/GridViewPager) for GridViewPager in GitHub.

Its layout XML implemented as below:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fragment instead of CardFragment and set your custom layout in onCreateView().

Comment: This is also a approach to this problem.Thanks for ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to use RelativeLayout as parent for your views

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by 
    fragment.setExpansionEnabled(false);